# large html not fully loading IE 11 / Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a 25MB all text html file saved locally on a windows 10 PC.  If I open the file in chrome it loads fully after about 5 seconds.  In IE 11 or Edge only about 3/4 of the page displays and it never fully loads.
Is there a way to get IE / Edge to fully load a large file like this, or is there a way to compress the text within the html page so that it will display?
Using gzip the text compressed to about 1Mb.  This is not a file being transferred from a web server, I am creating the file locally to display as a report to the user.
Thank you

Comment: Any chance you can provide the file? Also feel free to file a bug on us at bugs.microsoftedge.com - does it open fine in Firefox/Safari as well?

Comment: The file contains confidential data but I will look into scrubbing it.  It opens slightly faster in Firefox 59 than chrome.  I do not have access to safari.

Comment: The file also loads correctly in Opera. 
I have the code scrubbed it is basically 20+Mb of
`<HR WIDTH="100%"><pre STYLE="text-align: left">
<FONT SIZE=1>
XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXX XX                                 XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXX                                XX/XX/XX XX:XX XX  XXXX X
</pre>
`

Comment: It opening in Opera makes sense as that uses the Blink engine which powers Chrome as well. At this point, I highly recommend filing the bug at bugs.microsoftedge.com and mark it as private - then provide me with the bug number and make sure to attach the scrubbed file. I could spend time building out a 20MB file but for all I know there are some mixture of Unicode chars in a certain doctype that are causing it to not to repro.

Comment: I am working with IT to get past a certificate error at login.windows.net
but will post there when it is squared away.

Comment: I have created Issue #16515433
Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I repro the issue - looking at the scrollbar (and the devtools confirms this) we have all of the content to do layout correctly, but we must have some limit for rendering or even possible lower than us for rendering on the GPU. At any rate, I've passed it off to the rendering team to investigate. Looking at your code, I can't think of any way to work around this besides breaking up your content via paging or similar approach.